# I am having a problem linking EEL to a HTML document

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

hey guys so im trying to make a gui using EEL any python but when I follow all the guides my html file has a problem importing eel. I get an error 404 saying eel.js could not be found. I figure this is a linking issue but is there any way for me to resolve this. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does the file `eel.js` exist at that location?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem thank you, once I launch the py file it creates one